# Is there a way to filter and limit rows in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, filter, datagridview, datatable, limit

I'm writing a sale program, for this I need a browse window where the user can browse all the products he have for sale. This could mean thousands of products so filtering is the only way to go. I found that the quickest way to filter is to fill up a DataTable with the products (rather then filling the DataGridView directly, which was my first solution) and use its filtering abilities.

```
private void nameTB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    browseDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "name LIKE '%" + nameTB.Text + "%'";
}
```

This gets the job done for only visualizing what the sales person (from now on: user) is looking for and it worked perfectly for about 300 rows (products).
Increasing this to 10000 products (which is not just for test its a current database from a shop) and loading times grew exponentially from 1 second to 40, which in a sales environment is unacceptable.

The products are in a  MySQL database in the background. The query and saving it to a DataTable takes less then a second which is acceptable for 10000 products, the problems come when i try to visualize it. A simple:

```
datagridview1.DataSource = browseDataTable;
```

Takes around 4 seconds which would be acceptable, but for this application i need to add styles to my 6 columns + header (all of the columns have different fonts, some wrap, some don't, etc.) which increases the loading time to around 40 seconds, but without the styles, on a lower quality touch monitor in a well lit room, the user wont be able to see the rows.
Limiting it was the way to go, i didn't find any better solutions then to use something like this

```
browseDataTable.AsEnumerable().Take(100).CopyToDataTable(visibleDataTable, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
datagridview1.DataSource = visibleDataTable;
```

This makes visualizing it 1 second again.

**My problem is when i try to use the limit together with the filtered products (Visualize only the first 100 of the filtered rows).** Trying to combine which DataTable should be the DataSource of the DataGridView like this:

```
browseDataTable.AsEnumerable().Take(100).CopyToDataTable(visibleDataTable, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges); //done once somewhere

    private void nameTB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(nameTB.Text == "")
            datagridview1.DataSource = visibleDataTable;
        else
        {
            browseDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "name LIKE '%" + nameTB.Text + "%'";
            datagridview1.DataSource = browseDataTable;   
        }
    }
```

Didn't work because usually there are still too many products up to 3 letters and after each letter there's a 5 second delay, after 3-4 letters, its instantaneous.

**The ideal solution would be something like this:**

```
private void nameTB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    browseDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "name LIKE '%" + nameTB.Text + "%'";
    browseDataTable.AsEnumerable().Take(100).CopyToDataTable(visibleDataTable, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
}
```

**But this doesn't work either because 'Take(100)' always take the first 100 from the DataTable, filtered or not.**

(Limiting the query itself won't work either because then there would be a query at every letter which with a networked server would increase network congestion and will be slow, especially if the user starts to write fast)

Comment: Take will not give an error if you an error if you get less than the value.  So try a number like 10000 that will return results under 5 seconds.

Comment: My problem isn't with Take not being enough, i could do that, but then it would be just as slow as the original because it would be the exact copy of the original, so in fact i could just use the original.

Comment: It would be slower only when you had less than the take number.

Comment: So you want me to take 10000 and copy it to a new DataTable, and then filter the new DataTable?

Comment: That is one way.  You can use the Count property in the RowFilter which is probably faster Count(*) < 10000.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: The exact row count of the table is 9854. Taking 10000 would copy the same exact table, using that to filter would be the same as using the original, only a bit slower because it has to make a copy too. Using the Count in RowFilter doesn't work either because it counts the whole Table not just the visible ones. So if its (in my example) Count(*) < 10000 it shows the whole table so i filter anything because the count is 9854, if its Count() < 100 it doesn't show any rows, because the count is higher

Comment: I said to use take instead of Count(*) < 10000.  Taking 10000 is looking for an extra 146 rows.  If you had a loop the took 100 at a time  the last loop would be reading 9800 to 9900 and would only read 46 extra rows (9900 - 9854).  But then the looping of 100 at a time would take longer than the one take of 10000.  It is a trade-off which method would be quicker.  The linq take is faster than using for loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is simpler then i thought

```
private void nameTB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    browseDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "name LIKE '%" + nameTB.Text + "%'";
    visibleDataTable = browseDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable().AsEnumerable().Take(100).CopyToDataTable();
    datagridview1.DataSource = visibleDataTable;
}
```

This filters to the letters I wanted, and limits the rows to 100, this makes the whole process instantaneous.